# PHP - working with array row

Tags: php, api, symfony

I wrote an API call in symfony to return all array data from database.

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = [];

    $users = $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();
    foreach ($users as $user){
        array_push($data, $user->getId());
        array_push($data, $user->getEmail());
        array_push($data, $user->getUsername());
    }

    return $data;
}
```

I got it like this

> 1,first@mail.com,userOne,2,second@gamail.com,userTwo

but I want to sort every group of data in new row like

> 1,first@mail.com,userOne,
>
> 2,second@gamail.com,userTwo

Comment: Just do `print_r(array_values($users));`

Comment: Isn't the thing returned by `findAll()` already an array of arrays? Just return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of previous answers are not so good in my opinion. You don't need additional **loop**, just create query. (And return with your needed hydration)

For example

```
public function test()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
        ->select('user.id, user.email, user.username')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(); // will return objects
        // ->getArrayResult() ->  will return array of arrays
}
```

**Place it in your user repository and then call it, not the findAll method.**

Comment: And this is a solution that worked for me. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it would be:

```
public function getData()
{
    $users = $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data[] = [$user->getId(), $user->getEmail(),$user->getUsername()];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Which removes the overhead of the function call `array_push()`.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 3 occurances in `$data` for each row returned from the database, instead load a single occurance for each returned row and put an array in it.

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = [];

    $users = $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();
    foreach ($users as $user){
        array_push($data, [$user->getId(), $user->getEmail(),$user->getUsername()]);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Can you say which line ?

Comment: Array,Array {"success":false,"data":null,"message":"Notice: Array to string conversion","code":500,"debug":{"trace":"#0 [internal function]... doesn't say

Comment: @developsss Yea stop using `echo` to print arrays. Use `var_dump()` instead to find out what they contain.

Comment: I think this error may be due to something you are doing Downline from this code

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = [];

    $users = $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();
    foreach ($users as $user){
        $data[$user->getId()][] = $user->getId();
        $data[$user->getId()][] = $user->getEmail();
        $data[$user->getId()][] = $user->getUsername();

    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for help but I did it like this and it works for me.

```
public function getData()
{
    $results = $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();

    $rows = [];

    $rows[] = array(
        "id",
        "username",
        "email"
    );

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $rows[] = array(
            $row->getId(),
            $row->getUsername(),
            $row->getEmail()
        );
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$users = $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();
$i=0;
foreach ($users as $user){
    $data[$i][] = $user->getId();
    $data[$i][] = $user->getEmail();
    $data[$i][] = $user->getUsername();
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.